# How to access list of email accounts with cPanel API?

Tags: php, api, cpanel

cPanel is a web server management application that we have installed on our servers. It has a [XML/JSON](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/ApiIntroduction)-based [PHP API](https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php) that we want to use to access data such as a list of all email accounts. This system is [huge](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Software+Development+Kit+Home), I could'nt find an answer to this anywhere. Does anyone know how to list email accounts with the cPanel API?

**Edit:** The function I need is `listpopswithdisk` ([docs here](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiEmail)) which lists email accounts under a given domain, but no idea how to call this function.

Answer (score 3):

I think anyone can get his/her websites cPanel email accounts by using this normal php script.
I am using this script for my personal work and it's working fine.

```
<?php
$domain = 'domain';
$username = 'username';
$quota = 'default_quota';
$mails = "/home/".$username."/.cpanel/email_accounts.yaml";
$mail_info = file_get_contents($mails);
$get_domain_mails = explode('account_count:',$mail_info);
foreach ($get_domain_mails as $accounts_email)
{
$acc = explode(' ',$accounts_email);
$m = $acc[1];
$clean = str_replace($m,"",$accounts_email);
$get_data = str_replace("accounts:","",$clean);

$exp_ag = explode("'",$get_data);
foreach ($exp_ag as $brk)
{
$ex = explode("diskquota",$brk);
foreach ($ex as $na)
{
$aex = explode('disk_mtime',$na);
$aarx = explode("diskused",$aex[0]);
foreach ($aarx as $tax)
{
$rexp = explode(":",$tax);
$reaexp = str_replace(" ","",$rexp[1]);
if ($reaexp!="")
{
$lex = explode($quota,$reaexp);
$naex = explode("\n",$lex[0]);
echo $naex[1]."\n";
}
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Good idea, but this would only work if you had installed cPanel yourself on your own server (with root access). On a shared hosting server this would not work.

Comment: Yes That's Right... :)

Comment: oh really?  floated my fun.... man.. how can i read mails on shared?  im pretty sure i found a way, im looking into reading directly from  e.g. `~/mail/domain/accountame/cur/*` using some kind of php exec, node, or curl/fopen.

Answer (score 1):

cpanel UAPI listpops should do the trick

```
UAPI Functions - Email::list_pops
```

Since you tagged PHP, heres the PHP example

```
$cpanel = new CPANEL(); // Connect to cPanel - only do this once.

// List all email addresses that contain "user".
$emails = $cpanel->uapi(
    'Email', 'list_pops',
    array(
        'regex'      => 'user',
        )
);
```

reference https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/UAPI+Functions+-+Email%3A%3Alist_pops

Also look into Afterlogic's WebMail Lite API, it has alot of bang-up functionality for that, including both for PHP and JS, and a REST API.

THe REST API states

```
GET /account/list
Returns list of users.

Required parameters:

* string token - token

Optional parameters:

* int page - page number of the list. Default value: 1

* int usersPerPage - number of users per page. Default value: 100

* string orderBy - sorting field. Accepted values: email / name / last login

* string searchDesc - search string used for looking up specific account

* string domain - domain

Return: array

Sample request:

http://yourdomain/rest.php/account/list?token=yourToken

curl -X GET -d "token=yourToken" http://yourdomain/rest.php/account/list

Sample response:

"result":
[
  {
     "Id": 32,
     "Email": "yourName@yourdomain.com",
     "FriendlyName": "Name"
  },
  {
     "Id": 33,
     "Email": "yourOtherName@yourotherdomain.com",
     "FriendlyName": "OtherName"
  }
]
```

http://www.afterlogic.org/docs/webmail-lite/integration-and-development/rest-api#get-/account/list

Comment: Afterlogic PHP API will only list those accounts which are contained in Afterlogic db. It's just a subset of cPanel's mail account list. If you have, let's say, 1000 mail accounts on your cPanel server and users ever logged in 100 of these accounts using Afterlogic, only these 100 accounts will be added to Afterlogic db.